# LINQ Query with multiple group by

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting output in the form of `list` as shown in the image.
[image: image shown contains two tables. 1st: I`am getting ,2nd: i want.]

Here `month` is a string, `year` an int.

Comment: what is your actual data in your table ?

Comment: This is my guess at what the OP wants since he didn't really explain... Groupby month and year then sum the active versions in the group to produce the version.

Comment: Actual data in table is the one I`m getiing with same datatype as shown in getting this part of image.So far i got 1st table with heading getiing this in image.

Comment: have a look at my answer. may be it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your table name is **CompanyInfo** then

**SQL Qyery :**

```
select 
    Company,
    Year,
    Month, 
    Max(ActiveVersion) as ActiveVersion 
from 
    CompanyInfo 
Group by 
    Company, 
    Year, 
    Month
```

**LINQ Query :**

```
var result = from comp in CompanyInfo
                    group comp by new { comp.Company, comp.Year, comp.Month } into grp
                    select new {
                             grp.Key.Company,
                             grp.Key.Year,
                             grp.Key.Month,
                             Version = grp.Max(a => a.ActiveVersion)};
```

**With Lambda Expression :**

```
var result = infos.GroupBy(grp => new { grp.Company, grp.Year, grp.Month })
            .Select(t => new CompanyInfo()
                {
                    Company = t.Key.Company,
                    Year = t.Key.Year,
                    Month = t.Key.Month,
                    ActiveVersion = t.Max(v => v.ActiveVersion)
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks... your ans is working... Bt now i`m  facing one issue.My every record has one primary key.but in grouping its getting lost.i tried by grouping with primary key also but then i`m getting all the records.Is there any way to push priamry key without grouping?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed the table from left image is `input` table:

```
var result = from i in input
             groupby new { i.Company, i.Year, i.Month } into g
             select new {
                 g.Key.Company,
                 g.Key.Year,
                 g.Key.Month,
                 Version = g.Select(x => x.Version).Last()
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Record> list = new List<Record>();
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Jan", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Jan", 2));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Jan", 3));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Feb", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Feb", 2));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Mar", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Mar", 2));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Mar", 3));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2014, "Apr", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2015, "Jan", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2015, "Jan", 2));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2015, "Feb", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2015, "Mar", 1));
        list.Add(new Record("ABC", 2015, "Apr", 1));

        var result =  from record in list
                      group record by new { record.Company, record.Year, record.Month } into g
                         select new {
                             g.Key.Company,
                             g.Key.Year,
                             g.Key.Month,
                             Version = g.Count()};
```